Quarkus v3 with RabbitMQ comma-separated hosts does not work
Like in Spring framework (spring.rabbitmq.addresses), is there a way to use comma-separated hostname names to connect to multiple rabbitmq nodes?

Since Quarkus 3.8 (Reactive Messaging 4.11.0) you can set a comma-separated list of host:port addresses with the addresses attribute: https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/latest/rabbitmq/receiving-messages-from-rabbitmq/#configuration-reference

Yes, you're right, just test it right, I've upgrade quarkus from 3.2.x to 3.9.3, and it works by using rabbitmq-addresses in my application.properties. Thank's for your response
